# Compare XML elements in MVC 4

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm making MVC 4 application for monitoring and management of windows services in a network. I read the Computers Names, their services and all other parameters from XML file and showing them in tables that can be reordered by the user.

My problem is:

I can't save new order of the tables (at least i have no idea how to do it). Every computer that i read from the XML file i store in the Computer class.

My question is:

How can i compare each of the objects of my class Computer with the XML elements of the file, so i can save the order inside the XML file.

here is my XML

Computer

- MachineName
- Username
- Password
- Domain
- Services
          Name 
          Name 
  Services
  Computer

and the Class has these parameters too + some other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use LINQ to XML to compare the two. Please refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx

To get the name of the first computer in the xml for example:

```
    Xelement xelement = Xelement.Load("file.xml");
    Ienumerable<XElement> computers = exelement.Elements();

    private Computer computer = new Computer();

    computer.Name = computers.First(x => x.MachineName);
```

Then you could add the computer items to a List and sort it by name etc by calling the 'orderBy' method on the list like:

```
list.OrderBy(x => x.MachineName);
```

Comment: Could you please add some context from the link you posted, a code example maybe? Also see the FAQ how to give a good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer